# How to split an equation given as a string into coefficients, variables and powers?

Tags: python, string, oop

So I have to create a program which takes a string in the following form:
`2x^3 + x^2 - 4` and calculate its derivative i.e. make it like this: `6x^2 + 2x`

So I'm creating a `class Monomial` that has three member variables: coefficient, variable name and power. In other words, I have to split the polynomial into monomials. Then I have to take each monomial and split it into the aforementioned variables. So `2x^3` would be represented as the following object: `Monomial(2, 'x', 3)`

However, how do I split the string like that specifically? I don't want to use 'SymPy' or other libraries for easy calculation of derivatives.

Comment: Does it always have exactly that shape?

Comment: Well, sometimes you can have only x^2 or only 3x, or even only x

Comment: Have you looked at sympy?

Comment: Hint: each term has an optional prefix of digits (your coefficient), optionally followed by a single letter (your variable), optionally followed by '^' and another string of digits (your exponent). Terms are joined with a '+' and optional whitespace. You should be able to scan a string character-by-character, notice the transitions between character classes, and use those transitions as split points...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
pattern = "(\d+)?([a-z])\^(\d+)"
result = re.match(pattern, "323x^22")
print result.groups()
```

produces:

```
('323', 'x', '22')
```

The explanation of the pattern is as follows:

Each of the parenthesis will contain a group, the first one matches digits, indicated by the "\d" and matches as many digits as possible, indicated by "+". The question mark indicates that if there is no match (because it is x^2 for example) that is OK. In the central group you see [a-z] which will match any single low-case letter. So, if you find "23c^2" it will match as well. Finally, you need to escape the "^" symbol, which has its own meaning in regular expressions, using "\^" instead.

```
result = re.match(pattern, "x^2")
print result.groups()
```

Now, for an input of "x^2" this code will produce:

```
(None, 'x', '2')
```

so just make sure to substitute None for 1.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to split the expression into simple bits, but we have to remove the spaces in you string.

```
simplerExpression = " "
expression = input("Expression to derive: ")
for x in range(len(expression)):
    if expression[x] != " ":
        simplerExpression = simplerExpression + expression[x]
```

Know you know all thats separating each monomial is a + sign, so we split up all the monomials into an array:

```
ARRMonomial = []
for x in range(len(simplerExpression)):
    if simplerExpression[x] != '+':
        ARRMonomial.append(monomial)
        monomial = 0
    else:
        monomial = monomial + simplerExpression[x]
```

What you do is because you know for sure that everything before an 'x' will be a coefficient you would loop through all the chars in the string until you find the x then convert them into int (if u need it). Also notice i only did this for + sign and not negative, this is because we need to negative the numbers later with this loop:

```
ARRCoefficients = []
for monomial in ARRMonomial:
    sign = 1
    pos = 0
    coefficient = ""
    while monomial[pos] != 'x' and pos <=  len(monomial)+1:
        if monomial[pos] = '-':
            sign = "-1"
        else:
            coefficient = coefficient + expression[pos]
        pos = pos +1
    #And if there is no coefficient then return 1
    if coefficient == "":
        coefficient = 1
    ARRcoefficient.append(coefficient)
```

Know you have a way to get the coefficient out. What you do is search for the value of the exponents. You do this by looping until you find an x and then use the numbers right after the '^'.

```
ARRExponents = []
for monomial in ARRMonomial:
    Xexists = True
    x = 0
    while monomial[x] != 'x':
        if x == len(monomial):
           Xexists = False
           break
        x = x + 1
    if monomial[x+1] == '^' and Xexists == True:
        for y in range(x+1,len(monomial)):
            exponent = exponent + monomial[y]
    elif Xexists == True:
        exponent = 1
    else:
        exponent = 0
    ARRExponent.append(exponent)
```

What you will end up with here is a list of the coefficients and the exponents of the xs (including x to the power 0) in order for you to put i your function monome. If you dont know how to do that:

```
for x in range(len(ARRExponent)):
    monome(ARRCoefficiant[x],'x',ARRExponent[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first split the initial string in monomes and identify the elements of each monome:

- an optional sign (default +)
- an optional coefficient (default 1)
- an optional group variable exponent (default x^0) - if only variable is present, then exponent is 1

It is now simple to process a string using `re` module:

```
def process(txt):
    monomes = []
    for elt in re.findall('([+-]?) *([\d]*)([a-zA-Z]?)(?:\^(\d+))?', txt):
        coeff, var, exp = None, None, None
        #print(elt)
        if elt != ('','','',''):
            if elt[1] == '':
                coeff = 1
            else:
                coeff = int(elt[1])
            if elt[0] == '-': coeff = - coeff
            if elt[3] == '':
                if elt[2] == '':
                    var = 'x'
                    exp = 0
                else:
                    var = elt[2]
                    exp = 1
            else:
                exp = int(elt[3])
                var = elt[2]
            #print ((coeff, var, exp))
            monomes.append(Monome(coeff, var, exp))
    return monomes
```

We now get:

```
>>> process(poly)
[Monome(2, 'x', 3), Monome(1, 'x', 2), Monome(-4, 'x', 0)]
```